# Add shifted unsigned bit to unsigned long long (64 bit)

Tags: c, bitmap, unsigned-integer

I am trying to perform the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{

     unsigned long long test = 100; //64 bits
     test = test + (1UL << 33); //assuming 64 bits

     printf("test value %u", test);

     return 0;
```

}

test prints 100. I was expecting it to add the shifted bit to it.

I can see that there is some issue with its size, as if I, for example add 1UL << 14
test would be equal to 16484.

I am testing it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1njSlGjU

How can I go about adding this? I noticed that on my gdb debugger, the code just skips the line that adds does the addition.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  Hopefully you'll get something like "warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int'" - faster than posting on SO.

Comment: I did see the warning..didn't occur to me that a zero output was related to the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printf function has different formats for different data types. You are using a variable with 'unsigned long long' type but in the printf you are using "%u" which only prints objects of the type "unsigned int". By giving it the wrong 'data type' specifier you cause an undefined behavior. You may refer to the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types.

For the right output:

```c
printf("test value %llu", test);
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually **is** adding the value, you just don't realize it, since you're printing it out with `%u`. This converts the value to an `unsigned int`, which means that it's just 100. If you print with `%llu` for `unsigned long long`, it'll print out correctly.

Comment: It doesn't "convert it" to `unsigned int`. It tells `printf` the type is `unsigned int`, which is wrong, and produces undefined behavior.